# Using SML/NJ's Lazy — expression should be 15, but it diverges

Tags: lazy-evaluation, sml, smlnj

I'm using SML/NJ v110.80 and Lazy.

I tried the following code in repl

```
Control.lazysml := true;
open Lazy;
fun f x = f x;
let val x = $(f(4)) in 15 end;
```

The last expression should be 15 but it diverges.

Did I make a mistake or it just works improperly?

Comment: Interesting question. Since this isn't standard SML, do you have any documentation that you can link to? (I suspect that the lack of documentation might be part of the problem, since this seems to be a somewhat experimental variation).

Comment: It turned out that it's my fault.I should write let val lazy x = $(f(4)) in 15 end;  http://www.geocities.jp/m_hiroi/func/smlnj16.html

Answer (score 0):

The OP writes:

> I find that it's my fault I should write
>
> ```
> let val lazy x = $(f(4)) in 15 end;
> ```
>
> I found this information here --http://www.geocities.jp/m_hiroi/func/smlnj16.html